# Comparing string for equality with == operator in python

Tags: python, string-comparison

So I am trying to compare two string variables with `==` and it is not working for some reason. For example this code

```
print(dictionary[0])
print("A")
print(dictionary[0] == "A")
```

prints out

```
A    
A
False
```

I don't understand why it returns `False` when they are clearly equal.

Comment: is your list of words sorted?

Comment: Yes it is, the problem I think is it's not comparing words correctly

Comment: Try `print(repr(dictionary[0]))`, you may have some extra characters hidden in `dictionary[0]`.

Comment: Maybe the str from the dicht is actually "A " (the letter A plus a space). Also print out the types of the bars to make sure they're the same.

Comment: Also, you may be comparing `unicode` to `bytes` strings

Comment: post the result of `print(dictionary)` may help understanding

Answer (score 1):

it works on me

```
dictionary = {0:"A"}
print(dictionary[0])
print("A")
print(dictionary[0] == "A")


result: 
A
A
True
```

possible reason is the length, maybe it contain space
try to use `strip()` to  remove the space or check the length of a string `len(dictionary[0])`

```
print(dictionary[0].strip() == "A")
print len( dictionary[0] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the output with your cursor - you'll see that first line contains some whitespaces. Basically, your last line is equivalent to:

```
print("A    " == "A")
```

To get rid of those empty spaces, use [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) method:

```
print(dictionary[0].strip())
print("A")
print(dictionary[0] == "A")
```

There are also [lstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) and [rstrip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) methods, removing whitespaces only on the left or right side of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You might be in this situation

```
class Alike(object):

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        """called on =="""
        return False

    def  __repr__(self):
        """called on print"""
        return "A"

a_obj = Alike()
print(a_obj, a_obj == "A")
```

Make sure to know exactly what is stored in your dictionary. It is not because two objects prints the same way that they are equals.

You can try to make this to know more about it:

```
print type(dictionary[0]), len(dictionary[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your list contains a string with whitespaces at the end or the item number 0 is not a string, but an object, that is printed as an "A".

```
class hex_number:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number = number

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%X' % self.number


d = {0:'A  ', 1:hex_number(10)}
for i in range(2):
    print '{}: <{}>; <{}> == <{}>? => {}'.format(i,d[i],d[i],"A",d[i]=="A")
```